# How to change Font style in Html widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added post description from Json Rest API using HTML package in flutter. The default font size looks too small. How to increase the font size of below content - Html( data: user['news_description'],),

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

    class NewsDetails extends StatelessWidget {
          var user;
          var image_url = 'http://example.com/news/upload/';
          NewsDetails(this.user);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(image_url + user['news_image'],  width: double.infinity, height: 300.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                    SizedBox(height:5.0),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(user['news_title'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
                          SizedBox(height:10.0),
                        Html( data: user['news_description'],)
                        ],
                      )
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using `flutter_html` for richtext html.

Try this code to change the `Html` font style:

```
Html(
    data: 'my text',
    style: {
    "body": Style(
    fontSize: FontSize(18.0),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    },
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the latest version flutter html 2.2.1

Comment: but now, in 2022 its not working, what is the approach now ?

Comment: I set font size to 17 sp, but it not display properly. I almost cannot read because its very small. It happened in certain device. Do you know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 7):

You could use **customTextStyle** to change the font size.

```
customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
              return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 28));
              }
```

Complete example,

```
 Html( data: user['news_description'],
       customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
                  return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 28));
                  })
```

Comment: how to change width of table in flutter which show full screen width?

Comment: Upvote for this answer. But I have a little issue. What if I want to use the newest version of this package? It does not seem to have kept this `customTextStyle` property...

Comment: what is dom.Node node

Answer (score 4):

**We can use `defaultTextStyle` Try this code**

```dart
    Html(
     data: "<b>Hai</b>",
     defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 15,
       color: Colors.blue,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
```

Comment: is there a missing " on the data

Comment: @GoldenLion Thanks for giving feedback. I updated the changes.

Answer (score 3):

In year 2022, with new version of [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#style) package. To set style for html we do the following:

```
data: '<p>HTML text</p>',
style: {
    // p tag with text_size
    "p": Style(
           fontSize: FontSize(16),
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
           backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
         ),
},
```

Answer (score 2):

To change Html text style (color, size, style...) you can try:

```
Html(
      data: '${controller.product.value.description}',
      style: {
        'p': Style(
          color: Colors.grey
        ),
        'h4': Style(
            color: Colors.redAccent
        )
      },
    ),
```

and to change all text you can use: '*': Style(...),

Answer (score 0):

For text color just use ColorFiltered

```
ColorFiltered(
 colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.srcIn),
 child: Html(data: data)
)
```